# iPhone why am i leaking an object?

Tags: iphone, memory, uibutton, memory-leaks

I'm busy with an iPhone app. I've read quite a few things about memory management and i think i've got i covered pretty well. But when i'm running leaks it shows me that i'm leaking memory although i think im not.

Its the following code:

```
UIButton * plus = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect] retain];
[plus setTitle:@"+" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[plus addTarget:self action:@selector(plusClicked:) forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)UIControlEventTouchDown];
plus.frame = CGRectMake(x+35, y-30, 35, 30);
plus.tag = i;
[self.view addSubview: plus];
[plus release];
```

(the x/y/i vars etc... are defined above and not relevant in this code).

Can anybody explain why i'm leaking the plus object, according to instruments/leaks?

Answer (score 1):

1) There is not enough information to tell for sure, but my guess it's because your controller instance (or it's view) is leaking because after `[plus release]` the only owner of this button is controller's view.

2) You don't have to retain autoreleased objects to work with them in local scope - they are guaranteed to survive until drain of autorelease pool (which happens at the end of event handling in your case).

Comment: 1) There is not enough information to tell for sure, but my guess it's because your controller instance (or it's view) is leaking because after [plus release] the only owner of this button is controller's view.


>> Correct.. At a later time i'm deallocing this object and [super dealloc] gets called + some other cleanup.. That shouldn't leak should it?

Comment: Are you sure your controller's `dealloc` is actually called? "i'm deallocing this object" sounds suspicious to me - I hope you don't call `dealloc` directly, don't you?

Comment: Haha no ofcourse not! ;) I've got a NSLog in the dealloc (its in every dealloc just to know how things come and go, good for my learning process) and it prints when im releasing that object.. So the dialog is dealloced neatly..

Comment: Well, without code I can think about two ways to find the bug: 1) find all entries of `plus` in your code and carefully reason about memory management in each case 2) implement temporary subclass of `UIButton` and overload `retain`, `release` and `autorelease` in it. Don't change anything in your code except button allocation - `[MyTempButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect]`. With breakpoints in this methods and debugger you can find culprit (object which retains this button but doesn't release it) with 0.999 probability.

Comment: I already tried the first case (all the places where plus is used are visible in my code snippet on this page), and that (unfortunateley) didn't work. The second one seems to be a possibility, but is surely a last resort as that would take some (imho ugly) work to fix such a small item ;)

Answer (score 1):

This little bit of code retains on the plus button three times. Once in creating the button, once explicitly, and once in addSubView:.

This code also autoreleases the plus button once, and releases it once. (As mentioned in other answers, the explicit retain/release calls are unnecessary, but balanced so don't cause the leak.) Either you don't balance the retain in `addSubView:` with a release or the autorelease pool is not drained.  A possible solution is send a `release` (or possibly a `removeFromSuperview`) message to the plus object before releasing the containing view.  Another possible solution is to make sure the an autorelease pool is active when this code runs is drained.  Just to test, you can add an `NSAutoreleasePool` before your code, then drain the pool with something like:

```
NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

// your code

[pool release];
```

If this fixes it, check the structure of your code to figure out why your autorelease pool isn't draining.

Comment: You say im releasing twice, one autorelease and one "hard" release. The last release should be when i deallocate the parent view, which should be removing all sub-views, and by doing so send a release to all sub-views (cause who retains should release at some point). My question is why this last release isn't happening. In my eyes a 'removeFromSuperView' should be unnecessary because the parent-view should do this in the deallocate. Plus i've got to keep a reference to that plus button, which shouldn't be.. Also the autoreleasepool could be a solution, but i want to understand why this happens

Comment: You are correct, a simple release is sufficient. A removeFromSuperview would result in a release, but may be more than required. Are you releasing the plus button object in your view's dealloc method?

Comment: No, i havent got a reference to the plus object and i dont want to. Its just in that method's scope and it has to stay there, in my eyes there is no need for a reference in that object, i dont need to care about it after i've done the creating & adding to view. If i would follow your path, i should have to remove all objects in my view manually, and by doing so keep references to all objects on screen... Am i right?

Comment: You do need to balance the retain in your call to addSubview. Since I only see this tiny window into your system, I'm not sure where to balance that retain call with a release.  Also, you do have a reference to the plus object in your view's deallocate method. It's in the view's subviews property.

Comment: Ah, i didn't know that, sorry! But i'm wondering why iOS just doesn't remove the object when closing the view, and thus by doing so also releases it.. I thought that was the whole point of the iOS framework.. If you retain, you release, or else your wrong! With doing addSubview im handing the responsibility of allocating/releasing to the iOS framework and let the framework handle it.. I just want to understand why this isn't working as i thought it would :)

Comment: When it come's to the explaining the reasoning behind this issue I'm guessing a bit: I think the framework expects you to remove the subview. So the framework will release the subview when the subview is removed.  Since you're skipping that step, the release must be explicit.

Comment: UIButton * plus = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect] retain]; => Retaincount = 1


[self.view addSubview: plus]; => Retaincount = 2 (but in my hands its still 1 since addSubView is an iOS method, not some methof of my own)


[plus release]; => Retaincount = 1 (but in my hands its 0, cause of the iOS method)


This is what i'm thinking, is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not allocating that Button(plus button). If you are not allocating then you should not release that. Remove [plus release];

Comment: but he added "retain" when he initialized it... (not really needed, in this case... could remove both retain and release...)

Comment: Hmm, so far i've read that if you're not doing an alloc, you get an autorelease object. If you want to work with that object you need to retain it, just like i do. After that (i add it to a subview, which should do a retain) i release it.

Comment: Hi boney he is retaining the plus object which is autorelease. and releasing in last so there is no memory leak . @Nick sometime instrument shows wrong leak message .

Comment: @nick: well, you can work with it while you are in the same method... "plus" will be visible and you can call it untill your method end (and inside it)... you need to retain it (and to declare it outside of your method) just in case you need it outside and wanna be sure it remain in memory as far as you need...

Answer (score 0):

Just from the code snippet you posted, it doesn't look like a leak. If you remove the release line as suggested by makboney, you have to also remove the retain of the plus button at the beginning. There's no reason to retain it because it's returned autoreleased and you obviously do not plan to retain the ownership for longer than a couple of lines of code ;)

Try to run the static analyzer (Build->Analyze) maybe it will tell you more about the leak.

Answer (score 0):

remove `retain`, from `UIButton * plus = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect] retain];`
And remove 
`[plus release];`